# Converting to datetime - ParserError: Unknown string format: 2022-02-17 7

Tags: pandas, datetime, error-handling

I have a pandas dataframe with some string values that have the hour of a date in one-digit format if the hour is smaller than 10, like this:

```
2022-02-17 7
```

I now want to get this strings to datetime format but when applying

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], infer_datetime_format=True)
```

I get a ParserError:

```
ParserError: Unknown string format: 2022-02-17 7
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime':['2022-02-17 7']})
df['datetime'] = df['datetime'].str.replace(' (\d{1})', ' 0\\1')
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H')
```

The result:

[image]

A more general case which can handle two-digits too:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime':['2022-02-17 17', '2022-02-17 7']})
df['datetime'] = df['datetime'].str.replace('\s(\d)$', ' 0\\1')
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: This gives me a ValueError: `ValueError: time data 2022-02-17 7 doesn't match format specified`

Comment: See the updated code.